# Can Python directly read in a Hive table?

Tags: python, hadoop, hive

Is there a module or a connector that allows Python directly access Hive tables? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python has a `Pyhive` library that you can use to connect to hive database and run query against them.

it allows you to connect through JDBC and Kerberos Authentication.  However, it's bit buggy and JDBC over SSL seems not supported.

This is how you connect

```
connection = hive.connect(host='HIVE_HOST',
                          port=10000,
                          database='temp',
                          username='HIVE_USERNAME',
                          password='HIVE_PASSWORD',
                          auth='CUSTOM')
```

You can find more details here.

http://allabouthadoop.net/how-to-access-hive-with-python-script/

And these are the two issues I am talking about

- https://github.com/dropbox/PyHive/issues/258
- https://github.com/dropbox/PyHive/issues/257

Comment: Nit : `pyhive` does not use JDBC protocol ; it's a DBI wrapper around the Hive wire protocol (i.e. Thrift), just like the JDBC driver or the ODBC driver

Comment: Alternative to `pyhive` : `impyla` (courtesy of Cloudera) ; they depend on different SASL and Kerberos libs that are have their own bugs, and may require specific patching on specific version. Try both, if one works out of the box, use it and never upgrade !

Comment: Thanks a lot! I also found this link is helpful: http://dwgeek.com/guide-connecting-hiveserver2-using-python-pyhive.html/